# How to speed up rsync task for handling large volume?

Tags: rsync

I have a system with 12T usage, CentOS 6, raid6, xfs, email system

I need to rsync the data to standby server, now it takes around 6 hours to finish the task

I found that the volume of really copied file is not too much, around 100k files, but the latency seems to scanning the changes of folders

What can I do to improve the performance of rsync? Target is within 15 minutes, is it possible?

Comment: This question might be better for ServerFault.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up rsync?](https://superuser.com/questions/109780/how-to-speed-up-rsync)