# rsync too slow between local disks. how to solve?

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm not experienced in commandline utilities but I've tried to set up rsync to synchronize my document folder in linux mint to usb stick daily.

It works fine, all files are up to date.
the command in crontab is:

```
rsync -avu --inplace --delete -s /home/user/Documents /media/user/usb-drive
```

but it works too slow from my perspective - there is ~35Gb of the various files, including a few large files: ~5Gb.

when I drop a couple jpegs into the folder, each file is 1Mb, I expect that sync process should take a seconds or less, but it takes ~20+ mins.
if I look at the output then I see that rsync go throu all files! (thousands of those are not changed!, e.g. large files take a lot of time to sync).

I was using various software for win10 and it worked as expected - sync was performed on new or updated files only, no walk throu all files and folders.

is there some rsync option to make this quicker? to prevent full resync each time?

Comment: Some potential options at https://superuser.com/questions/109780/how-to-speed-up-rsync

Comment: What does `--itemize` say about the sync process? What filesystem is used on /media/user/usb-drive? Is it capable of storing all of the metadata that `-a` is telling rsync to copy? (Ownership? Permissions? Precise timestamps?)